# KVM virt-install wont install VM because of unsupported configuration

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

i have a problem with my ubuntu server on which i installed kvm and virt-install so i can run a VM. I tried to install the VM with the following command showed below in the code but i get an error of unsupported configuration.. I am also trying to install it on the home directory because i have a special place assigned for my VMs as showed below.. Can you tell me how can i resolve this issue?

Just to be clear, the installation is not successful.

Thank you

```
kingdev@devpc:/home/kvmimages/ubuntu1$ sudo virt-install --name ubuntu-guest --os-variant ubuntu22.0 4 --vcpus 2 --ram 2048 --location http://ftp.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/installer-amd64/ --n etwork bridge-virbro, model=virtio --graphics vnc --disk path=/home/kvmimages/ubuntu1/ 
WARNING Graphics requested but DISPLAY is not set. Not running virt-viewer. 
WARNING No console to launch for the guest, defaulting to --wait -1 

Starting install... 
Retrieving 'linux' 
Retrieving 'initrd.gz' 
11 MB 00:00:10 49 MB 00:00:50 
ERROR unsupported configuration: storage type 'dir' requires use of storage format 'fat' 
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful. 
If it was, you can restart your domain by running: 
virsh --connect qemu:///system start ubuntu-guest 
otherwise, please restart your installation.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a while back but I just had the issue and found it was due to the ISO being in its own directory. The issue completely disappeared when I placed the ISO into the main directory and refreshed the list. You could alternatively add the directory with a single ISO to your list of sources, but I wanted to keep my list shorter.

Comment: Worked for me +1